# Send image and text from android to wcf service

Tags: android, wcf, upload

I'm trying to upload an image and a text to a wcf service. I create a service to save upload images:

```
                <OperationContract()> _
                <WebGet(UriTemplate:="UploadFile",      
    BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)>
     Function UploadFile(ByVal fileStream As Stream)
```

That uploadFile function is like this:

```
   Function UploadFile(ByVal fileStream As Stream) Implements      IServiceApp.UploadFile
    Dim FilePath As String = Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/fh/adds")

    Dim fileToupload As FileStream = New FileStream(IO.Path.Combine(FilePath, "fass.png"), FileMode.Create)

    Dim bytearray(8192) As Byte

    Dim bytesRead As Integer, totalBytesRead As Integer = 0
    Do
        bytesRead = fileStream.Read(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead
      fileToupload.Write(bytearray, 0, bytearray.Length)
    Loop While bytesRead > 0


    fileToupload.Close()
    fileToupload.Dispose()
End Function
```

Also my android code to send an image to server is here:

```
     File file = new    
            File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                        "temp_photo.jpg");
             Log.d("errrr", "1");
              try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.****.com/ServiceApp.svc/UploadFile()");
                    Log.d("errrr", "2");
                    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
                            new FileInputStream(file), -1);
                    Log.d("errrr", "3");
                    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
                    Log.d("errrr", "4");
                    reqEntity.setChunked(true); // Send in multiple parts if needed
                    Log.d("errrr", file.getPath());
                    httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    Log.d("errrr", "6");
                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

                    //Do something with response...

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // show error
                    Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```

But when I ran the app, nothing saved in server and nothing shown as toast error message. 
Where is the problem? I also used webhttpbinding.

Comment: Debug and check step by step.

Comment: At 'HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost)' line an error occurred. But I don't know what is that.

Comment: You should better look in the LogCat. As you will or have a NetworkOnMainThreadException. Or, if you did put your code in an AsyncTask or thread, the Toast() in the catch block would blow your app if something went wrong.

Comment: Ok, The problem was NetworkOnMainThreadException. But nothing saves on the remote server now. Why?

Comment: How did you solve the exception problem?

Comment: I add these code before connecting to server: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

Comment: But the main problem exist. I can't upload anything. I guess my server code not call.